# Core Rulebook Battle Royale

Tags: pathfinder-1e, optimization, player-vs-player

My group will be having a one-off battle royale before our next session, with the following conditions:

1. Core Rulebook only (races, items, classes, feats, etc.)
2. Level 10, with standard starting gold
3. The arena will be circular in shape and of finite height
4. Scrolls / items that cast spells above your caster level are banned

I've been thinking of interesting tactical ideas that fit within this framework, and have come up with the following:

1. Druid 10 - wild shape into Large Earth Elemental, Earthglide beneath enemy characters and drag them into the Earth, suffocating them
2. Paladin 10 - abuse high saves and LoH to provide the opportunity to land huge smites on casters and sunder the weapons of any martial characters
3. Rogue 4/Assassin 2/Fighter 4, providing improved uncanny dodge and poison use, plus some feats to better land the poisons
4. Play a Wizard.  Cast suggestion, make allies, then kill them.

I'm thinking that #4 might inevitably be the strongest option.  Do any of you have anything else up your sleeves?  Working with only the Core Rulebook really hamstrings non-Wizard options, in my view.

Comment: This is a really nifty question seeking expertise from other Pathfinder players on helping optimize an interesting arena. I encourage people reading this to consider that what he's asking is extremely specific in that it's looking for optimized combos based on his listed framework to be used in game. Great question. I recommend updating the question to make it clearer that you're asking for help optimizing challenging character builds following your framework. The question just seems buried under the text here, so make it prominent.

Comment: The thing is, this is asking for literally any powerful build that can be created using the included constraints, and said contraints aren't nearly constraining enough to handle such a wide scope. Voting to close as too broad.

Answer (score 2):

The way to win a battle royale is to prevent people from attacking you (so that they attack each other instead).

Use evasion spells such as Invisibility and Fly. Move around unpredictably, and give your DM your location secretly, so that people can't hit you with AoE spells like Glitterdust or Dispel Magic or Fireball. When attacking, use lots of summoned monsters (consider Silent Spell so people can't hear you spellcasting).

Use save-or-lose spells targeting each of the three saves. In particular consider Blindness to shut down enemy wizards.

Single-use items such as scrolls and potions are very strong in arena battles. Most of your inventory should be scrolls.